# How to upgrade geoserver 2.18 bin.zip to geoserver 2.21 windows installer ( as a service)

Tags: service, upgrade, geoserver

I am trying to upgrade geoserver from version 2.18.0 bin.zip  to version 2.21.1 (windows installer). If I understand correctly, then 2.18.0 uses a jetty server, and no jetty installation is required, this is provided by the geoserver.
Version 2.18 uses a jetty server, and no jetty installation is required, this is provided by the geoserver. I installed 2.21.1 using the windows installer, first specifying the default address of the data folder. Everything seems to be installed, but the service starts and immediately turns off. How to overcome it? Do I need to install Tomcat first? Do I need to remove the jetty server, if so, how?  In the installation of the log - only 3 lines:

> ERROR : Nothing to start, exiting ...
>
> Usage: java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar [options] [properties]
> [configs] java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --help # for more
> information
> Why is the jetty server listed in the log and not the tomcat?

Comment: On the user list there are reports that the build of the windows installer is broken (None of the main devs use windows so we rely on users to check it and no one did for this release). You can continue to use the platform independent binary version (jetty) but it is not for production. Make sure to have backed up your data directory before upgrading

Comment: 1. Is there any Geoserver version  that works on Windows so that it works as a service?

Comment: Install tomcat as a service and add the war file to that

Comment: 2. Is it correct to expect that the Windows installer will be brought up and tested?     3. The initial task is to keep the server running all the time. How to restart the server is clear, but how to optimally determine that it is stopped for any reason?

Comment: I have not worked with war files, what can I read to correctly write the file and where to add it? I will install tomcat and will try to add war file. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do I understand correctly that 1.if there is no war file for tomcat, then the geoserver will work with jetty, otherwise it will work with tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, all works!
So to upgrade geoserver from 2.18 bin.zip to geoserver as service :

1. Install Tomcat as a service
2. download  Web Archive (instead of Platform independent binary and not windows installer)
3. Unpack downloaded archive and copy geoserver.war to webapps directory of Tomcate (in my case C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat
   8.5\webapps)
4. Restart Tomcate service
5. In webapps folder of Tomcat will appear directory

> geoserver

5. Store your saved geoserver data folder to geoserver/data directory of Tomcate
6. restart Tomcat and enjoy